# ExtJs4, how to edit manually cell datetime with text format (without timefield or datefield) in gridpanel?

Tags: datetime, date, format, extjs4, gridpanel

With GridPanel in ExtJs4, how to edit cell `datetime` (without `timefield` or `datefield`) ?

I use this for a correct display :

```
{
    header: 'date_event',
    field: {
        type: 'datecolumn',
        // format: 'Y-m-d H:i'  // do nothing on rendering ou editing
    },
    renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('Y-m-d H:i')
}
```

But, when I edit my cell rendered as `2011-09-08 09:18`, the input was transformed :

```
Thu Sep 08 2011 09:18:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)
```

Can I keep the format render for editing?

Alternativly, using `type: 'datecolumn'` and `xtype: 'datefield'` or `timefield` is working fine.

But without `datetimefield`, I was unable to edit both date and time.

Preferring using a full date and time editor, how to edit it in text format formatted by my date pattern?

```
{
    header: 'date_event',
    xtype: 'datecolumn', // convert with locale FR (without displaying hours) : 08/09/2011 
    field: {
        xtype: 'datefield', // can edit days
        // xtype: 'timefield',  // can edit hours
        // xtype: ['datefield','timefield'],    // don't work
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom component that holds **datefield** and **timefield** together  in **hbox** layout container. Implement **setValue**, **getValue** and other essential methods (if any) that affects both containing components. **alias: 'widget.mydatepatterfield'**. I think this approach will solve your problem.